# Physical interpretation of relativistic velocity (distance by proper time)

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, velocity, inertial-frames

In special relativity (SR), momentum is defined as
$\frac{mv}{\sqrt {1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

While one way of interpreting the relativistic momentum is to consider the mass to be the "relativistic mass" $m_r = m/\sqrt {1 - v^2/c^2}$, the other way is to consider the velocity as a "relativistic velocity":
$v_r = \frac{v}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$
or, $v_r = \frac{v}{\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}}$, where $\beta = v/c$.

This can be rewritten as:
$v_r = \frac{dx}{dt}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}}) = \frac{dx}{dt\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}} = \frac{dx}{d\tau}$, where $\tau$ is the proper time.

What is the physical interpretation of this relativistic velocity? If we visualize this on a space-time diagram, an observer on the rest frame, observing the moving body, appears to be taking the ratio of a space interval $dx$ of the moving body as measured from his rest frame, with a proper time interval $d\tau$ that has meaning only on the frame of the moving body (i.e. the proper time measured by a clock attached to the moving body).  Essentially, it appears to be a velocity greater than the observed velocity $dx/dt$ of the body, but how do we give it a physical meaning?

Comment: why should there be an interpretation, except by the increasing mass.

Comment: Thats's the reason why you can travel to the Andromeda galaxy in 1 year proper time while it is millions of light years away, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intergalactic_travel#Time_dilation

Comment: Arguably, it's just gauge-fixing an unphysical degree of freedom of the theory.

Answer (score 1):

It is the momentum per unit mass.

By the way, the concept of relativistic mass is strongly deprecated now. Any treatment that you are studying which mentions it in anything other than a historical context is probably a poor source to be learning from.

Answer (score 1):

$v_r$'s physical interpretation the space-component of the Lorentz covariant 4-velocity:

$$ u^{\mu} = \frac 1 {\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}(c, {\bf v})$$

which agrees with @Dale's answer, since:

$$ p^{\mu} = mu^{\mu} = (\gamma mc, \gamma m{\bf v}) = (E/c, {\bf p}) $$

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @JEB's answer,
the "spatial-component of the 4-velocity [vector]" can be visualized on a spacetime diagram as the space-component $PV$ of the 4-velocity vector $OV$.

[image: components-rapidity-robphy]

Your description of

> the ratio of a space interval  of the moving body as measured from his rest frame, with a proper time interval  that has meaning only on the frame of the moving body (i.e. the proper time measured by a clock attached to the moving body)

is $\displaystyle\frac{\mbox{opposite}}{\mbox{hypotenuse}}=\sinh\theta$ in a Minkowski-right triangle $OPV$, with reference to the Minkowski-angle (the "rapidity") $\theta$ between two worldlines.
The spatial-velocity is $v=c\tanh\theta$ and the time-dilation factor is $\gamma=\cosh\theta$.

This $\gamma v=c\sinh\theta$ is sometimes called the **"celerity"** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_velocity ,
which (I think) is a better name than "proper velocity".

Of course, we use [spatial-]velocity to describe the motion of a particle [with timelike (or lightlike) momentum]. **However, just because a quantity has the units of velocity, 
I don't think that it must be interpreted as in the previous sentence (although one can search, as you did).**

In my opinion,
@JEB's answer as "space-component of the Lorentz covariant 4-velocity" is the simplest and clearest. In the context of 4-momentum that you provided, @Dale's answer is a good interpretation (as the spatial-component of the 4-momentum divided by the magnitude of the 4-momentum [the invariant-mass]).

Finally...
Note that, in Minkowski spacetime geometry, since $\gamma\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}=\cosh\theta \geq 1$,
 the magnitude of the spatial-component of a timelike unit-vector (the celerity)
is greater than the magnitude of the slope (the spatial-velocity):
$$\gamma v =\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}=\sinh\theta =\cosh\theta \tanh\theta
\qquad \geq \qquad \tanh\theta=v,$$ 
as you found.